# Asp.net mvc sql query as parameter to controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

I am trying to send a query like below from UI to controller.

```
name='abc' and title='def'
```

I am trying to use lambda expression on controller to filter this query. But I am struggling hard to pass ui query to controller and make it as lambda expression.

Could you please throw some idea with example where i can pass sql query(string) as parameter and use it in controller action method as lambda expression. Any link or logic should be fine for me to try further.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public virtual ActionResult QueriedProjects(string builtQuery)
 {
     var Helpera = new Helpera(true);

     var myProjectDetails = Helpera.myProjectDetails (null);
     var myProjectDetails = new myProjectDetails () 
     { GetMyProjectDetails = myProjectDetails  };
     return View(myProjectDeails)
 }
```

UI

on button click I am generating a query as string with entered values in query builder

Generated String: name='abc' and title= 'def'

Comment: You confused me...are you talking about url query string parameters? What have you done so far? Can you add some code to your question so we can properly "guess" what you are talking about?

Comment: sorry. I updated question. Please let me know if there is more confusion so that I can edit it again.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? I mean...why dont you pass those values to the controller action method?

Comment: What filtering values do you need to pass as lambda? Name and title only?

Comment: I have a jquery UI dialog which has query builder like TFS query builder. I am taking inputs filtered by user in query builder and pass them to controller and then generate lambda expression with those inputs. I had just given sample with name and title to get logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass values like this:

`Contoller/QueriedProjects?name=abc&title=def`

You need to have 2 parameters in your controller method like:

`public virtual ActionResult QueriedProjects(string name, string title)`